# Can we get Onedrive Users Data using (Azure AD App+PnP Powershell) without having admin center access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, onedrive-for-business, azureadapps

My Use case scenario:

We are using Azure AD App ("Application Permission") with PnPPowershell to get all the OnedriveUsers storage data.

My client is very limited to provide access andso don't have admin center access.

Queries:
1.Can we get Onedrive Users Data using PnP Powershell without having access on admin center?
2.To use "Get-PnPTenantSite", what is the minimum access/API permission is required.?